# Tried to register two views with the same name RCTVideo

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

**Current behavior :**

App crash

**Reproduction steps** :

I want to use the **react-native-video** library for videos in app, after installing this library the app crached and its displaying this error : tried to register two views with the same name RCTVideo.

**react-native** : 0.59.9

**react-native-video** : 4.4.2

---

[App Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYy0e.png)

**Expected behavior**:

App shouldn't be crash.

**Platform** : IOS, Android

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error. You have a node module dependency which internally uses `react-native-video`. In my case i used `react-native-gifted-chat` which uses `react-native-video`.

The path for my case was `PROJECT_DIR/react-native-gifted-chat/node_modules/react-native-video`

I deleted this folder and it resolved my issue. Please check which dependency is using react-native-video and delete its node module path to react-native-video.